# Laravel request update unique field only if changed

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, request

I want to be able to validate a user email address based on certain circumstances.

For example

> If a user is being created, the email address must be unique
>
> If a user is being updated but the email address hasn't changed, ignore the unique email rule
>
> If a user is being updated and their email address has changed, it has to be unique

I've had a little look around and I know that I can specify different rules based on the method like so

```
public function rules()
{
    $user = User::find($this->users);

    switch($this->method())
    {
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'user.email'      => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'user.email'      => 'required|email,
            ];
        }
        default:break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it so that in the put/patch case, the rule checks if the email address has been changed, and if it has then it has to be unique?

If not is there a cleaner way of achieving this goal? Maybe without the switch case? Perhaps more in depth validation rules I haven't stumbled across yet?

Comment: i have added an answer, check it once

Comment: @rkj I have taken the advice of another user and temporarily removed the switch statement to try and clean the code. If i resort back to the switch method I will try your answer, thank you.

Comment: no need to add switch condition for my answer, that one line will work for all create, patch

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice you had updated it to ignore the switch statement. Your answer works great, thanks!

Comment: glad it works for you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to add `unique` validation if email changed, if that is the case then you just need to add a condition in validation. If you check unique validation structure it look like this `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`, check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique)

So the validation will be look like this, when you will create new record `$userId` will be null but at time of patch it will have value. So this validation will work for both create and patch.

```
$userId = isset($user) ? $user->id : null;

$rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $userId.',id',
    ];

 $this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and found a tidy way of addressing it in the docs.

My issue was that if a user was already created, the email address claimed it wasn't unique, even if it was already registered to the user.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

A few headings down is something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$request->validate([
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

This does the following:

> Validate the email address, make it required and unique, unless the user ID of that row matches this user.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in feature for this. You can add the actual user id to the unique constraint, if present. This will ensure that the unique constraint will still work, but it will not fail when the value did not change:

```
$exists = $user->exists;
$rules = return [
    'user.email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email' . ($exists ? ','.$user->id : ''),
];
```

Internally, this will execute a query like:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE email = 'some-mail@example.com' AND id != 42
```

The latter part `AND id != 42` will only be part of the query when you add the third parameter to the unique validation rule.

Comment: This sounds logical, but it doesn't seem to work for me? It still errors out saying the email has to be unique if i don't change it. Does this have to be applied in the above `switch` statement or can it just be a general rule?

Comment: If there is not another good reason to have the switch other than the unique thingy, get rid of it - for the unique constraint you definitely don't need it. You only need a good and consistent way to determine if a user exists already. By the way, I had to fix the call to `$user->exists` because it shouldn't be a function call. It is a magic property.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be detecting correctly, its still returning 'email has already been taken'

Comment: @S_R did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `break;` statement after every `case.` And for Update (PATCH request) you have to pass `id` also in update request.

```
public function rules()
{
    $user = User::find($this->users);

    switch($this->method())
    {
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'user.email'      => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $user->id.',id',
            ];
        }
        break; // change here
        case 'PUT': break; // change here
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'user.email'      => 'required|email,
            ];
        }
        break; // change here
        default:break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->validate([
        'naam' => 'required|max:190|unique:database_name.table,column_where_you_check_unique,'.$id.',$id_column_reference'
    ]);
```

'naam' - form input field name

database_name(optional) - if you have multiple database

table(required) - table name

column_where_you_check_unique(required) - where data is unique

$id(required) - check with id autoincrement

$id_column_reference - column name of $id.

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
'slug' => $site->slug !== $request->slug ? 'required|min:4|max:80|unique:sites' : 'required|min:4|max:80'
```

Answer (score -1):

In your controller methods (store and update) you can use:

```
 $validations = [
        'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,email'
    ];

 $this->validate($request, $validations);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, Im struggling to see how this answers my question? This is the same as my switch method in my request, I need it to be able to detect if the email has changed in the POST and run a different unique rule if it has been changed

Comment: Do you have more code, controller, model and/or repository?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$exists = Section::where('code', $request->code)->exists();
        $isUpdateQuery = (($request->method() == 'PUT') || ($request->method() == 'PATCH'));
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            "code" => ['required','unique:sections,code' . (($isUpdateQuery && $exists) ? ',' . $request->code . ',code': '')],
            "title" => 'required | json',
            "subtitle" => 'required | json',
            "btn_title" => 'required | json',
            "name" => 'required',
            "pageID" => 'required | exists:pages,pageID',
            "image" => 'nullable',
            "btn_link" => 'nullable',
        ]);
```